# Datatable not returning rowid to asp.net mvc controller on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Am unable to get the rowids from the jquery datatable to my controller on form submit.

Please find below the html code:

```
 <form id="frm-example" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" method="POST">

    <table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "UserProfile")'" />
        <button type="submit" id="frm-example" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">Delete</button>

    </p>
<pre id="example-console">
</pre>
</form>
```

Please find below of my code for Datatable

```
 @* Load datatable css *@
 <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"    rel="stylesheet" />
 @* Load datatable js *@
 @section Scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        //
        // Updates "Select all" control in a data table
        //
        function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table) {
            var $table = table.table().node();
            var $chkbox_all = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
            var $chkbox_checked = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
            var chkbox_select_all = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

            // If none of the checkboxes are checked
            if ($chkbox_checked.length === 0) {
                chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
                if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
                    chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
                }

                // If all of the checkboxes are checked
            } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length) {
                chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
                if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
                    chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
                }

                // If some of the checkboxes are checked
            } else {
                chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
                if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
                    chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
                }
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Array holding selected row IDs
            var rows_selected = [];
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                'ajax': '/UserProfile/LoadData',
                'columnDefs': [{
                    'targets': 0,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'width': '1%',
                    'className': 'dt-body-center',
                    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox">';
                    }
                }],
                'order': [1, 'asc'],
                'rowCallback': function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    // Get row ID
                    var rowId = data['USER_ID'];

                    // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
                    if ($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1) {
                        $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                        $(row).addClass('selected');
                    }
                }, 'columns': [
                        { "data": "DT_RowId", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "USER_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "USER_NAME", "autoWidth": true }
                ]
            });

            // Handle click on checkbox
            $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
                var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

                // Get row data
                var data = table.row($row).data();

                // Get row ID
                var rowId = data['USER_ID'];

                // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs 
                var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

                // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
                if (this.checked && index === -1) {
                    rows_selected.push(rowId);

                    // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
                } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
                    rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
                }

                if (this.checked) {
                    $row.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $row.removeClass('selected');
                }

                // Update state of "Select all" control
                updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);

                // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
            $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function (e) {
                $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
            });

            // Handle click on "Select all" control
            $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table.table().container()).on('click', function (e) {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('#example tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
                } else {
                    $('#example tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
                }

                // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Handle table draw event
            table.on('draw', function () {
                // Update state of "Select all" control
                updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);
            });

            // Handle form submission event 
            $('#frm-example').on('submit', function (e) {
                var form = this;

                // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
                $.each(rows_selected, function (index, rowId) {
                    // Create a hidden element 
                    $(form).append(
                        $('<input>')
                           .attr('type', 'hidden')
                           .attr('name', 'id[]')
                           .val(rowId)
                    );
                });

            });


        });
    </script>
}
```

Please find below my code in controller.

```
  namespace DOSApplication.Controllers
  {

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string[] id)
        {


            return View("Index");
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The value in the Index action of home controller is showing null.

Comment: It looks like you're writing out to your console what the form looks like serialized.  What do you see in the javascript console?

Comment: There is a lot of code here... is all of it required to reproduce the issue? For example I'm pretty sure `updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl` is irrelevant to the problem at hand. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Kyle Gobel- i have changed the code its should return array of rowid's but now its returning null to the action method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // Handle form submission event 
  $('#frm-example').on('submit', function (e) {
      var form = this;
            console.log('ids: ', rows_selected)
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '',
        data: {
          id:JSON.stringify(rows_selected)
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log("You data will be saved, resposnse: ", response);
        }
      });
      return false
  });
```